# Firebase Auth Page Returns A Blank Page

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a web app with NavigationRail. I am trying to implement Firebase Authentication but could not make it work so far.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my AuthPage;

```
import 'package:bdkakademi/desktop/desktop_homepage.dart';
import 'package:bdkakademi/desktop/desktop_login_page.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AuthPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        StreamBuilder<User?>(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return const DesktopHomePage();
            } else {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  DesktopLoginPage(
                    emailController: TextEditingController(),
                    passwordController: TextEditingController(),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Any ideas what should i do?